# Duel boot ubuntu won't boot after install with Win 10

Tags: dual-boot

After a "successful" dual boot install. I rebooted my machine expected grub to load and give me the choice of ubuntu or Win 10.  My machine goes straight into windows.

I've disable the "secure boot" feature of UEFI and I'm currently at a loss.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing fn+f2 or f12 or even f8 depending on your make/model and changing the boot manager in settings. If you can't find grub, try writing the grub super disk iso to a usb flash drive and booting from it, then installing grub onto the mbr partition.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to download linux (i'd prefer Ubuntu) create Live USB of linux.
2. Restart and boot from your live USB (the same way as installing Ubuntu, but no need to Install)
3. U need to Install boot-repair, open terminal and:
   1)sudo apt-get update
   2)sudo apt-get install boot-repair
   3)y
4. open boot-repair via terminal:
   boot-repair
5. Follow steps untill finish
   And thats all you can restart your Computer it will start from GRUB
   PS: Hope i could explain and it helped you :))